# How do I tell Grunt to NOT minify or concatenate js files in a build task?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I've just scaffolded an Angular app using Yeoman. I've noticed that the `build` task does several things by default, including minifying and concatenating js files.

I'd like to have a simpler build task that didn't do any minifying or concatenation, and, instead, only did the following two things:

1. compile my .scss into .css
2. copy a working app into my distribution directory

Can anyone help me write a grunt task that will do (only) these two things?

Many thanks.

Comment: What's your gruntfile look like? You should just be able to remove the tasks you don't want to run.

Comment: Ok, I've added the gruntfile.

Comment: well, in the gruntfile you diplayed the `cssmin` task is commented out although you're calling it. Pretty sure that's related.

Comment: btw, aren't you just looking for a dev-build instead of a prod-build? I'm pretty sure (not 100%) yeoman will support both targets (dev and build) with the flip of a switch.

Comment: Thanks @Geert-Jan. Uncommenting cssmin was a step in the right direction. Yes, I'm trying to do a sort of dev-build instead of a prod-built.  I couldn't figure out how to get Grunt to do this out of the box, though, so I rolled my own solution. See below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I've edited the default grunt file so that it does what I want.

My solution involved writing tasks called `copy:devDist` and `compass:devDist`, and then combining them into a `devDist` task.

```
//
//  copy:devDist --> copies everything into the dist folder, except styles/
//
    copy: {
      [...]
      devDist: {         
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            '**','!styles/**'   // everything but styles/
          ]
        }]
      }
    },



//
//  compass:devDist --> compile the sass; put result in dist/styles/
//
    compass: {
      [...]
      devDist: {
        options: {
          cssDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles'  
        }
      }
    },




  //
  // register a 'devDist' task that calls the two tasks above
  //
  grunt.registerTask('devDist', [
    'clean:dist',
    'copy:devDist',
    'compass:devDist'
  ]);
```

Now running `grunt devDist` compiles my css and puts a fully functional app into my dist folder. Excellent. :)