# How to stop Grunt.js from minifying my Yeoman webapp

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, minify, yeoman

I'm trying to build my webapp using generator-webapp(sass w/compass + boostrap-sass). However, I don't want it to minify any of the files. (At least just the css, but ideally nothing will be minified). At my job I'll be doing a bit of backend that is done in .NET/C# as well as but mostly front end, hence why I need the HTML to not be minified so I can import the front end into Visual Studio and be able to manipulate it.

Currently, I'm trying to configure my gruntfile to stop the minification but I'm having a difficult time finding a solution.

Here is my gruntfile (it's just the default one that is generated)

```
// Generated on 2014-02-27 using generator-webapp 0.4.7
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

// Load grunt tasks automatically
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

// Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
require('time-grunt')(grunt);

// Define the configuration for all the tasks
grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    yeoman: {
        // Configurable paths
        app: 'app',
        dist: 'dist'
    },

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
        js: {
            files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
            tasks: ['jshint'],
            options: {
                livereload: true
            }
        },
        jstest: {
            files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
            tasks: ['test:watch']
        },
        gruntfile: {
            files: ['Gruntfile.js']
        },
        compass: {
            files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
            tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
        },
        styles: {
            files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
            tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
            },
            files: [
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
                '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png,svg,webp}'
            ]
        }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
        options: {
            port: 9000,
            livereload: 35729,
            // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
            hostname: 'localhost'
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                open: true,
                base: [
                    '.tmp',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>'
                ]
            }
        },
        test: {
            options: {
                port: 9001,
                base: [
                    '.tmp',
                    'test',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>'
                ]
            }
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                open: true,
                base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                livereload: false
            }
        }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                dot: true,
                src: [
                    '.tmp',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
                    '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
                ]
            }]
        },
        server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
            reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
        },
        all: [
            'Gruntfile.js',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '!<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
            'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
        ]
    },


    // Mocha testing framework configuration options
    mocha: {
        all: {
            options: {
                run: true,
                urls: ['http://<%= connect.test.options.hostname %>:<%= connect.test.options.port %>/index.html']
            }
        }
    },




    // Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
    compass: {
        options: {
            sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
            cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
            generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
            imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
            javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
            fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
            importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
            httpImagesPath: '/images',
            httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
            httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
            relativeAssets: false,
            assetCacheBuster: false
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated'
            }
        },
        server: {
            options: {
                debugInfo: true
            }
        }
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    autoprefixer: {
        options: {
            browsers: ['last 1 version']
        },
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css',
                dest: '.tmp/styles/'
            }]
        }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the HTML file
    'bower-install': {
        app: {
            html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
            ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/'
        }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    rev: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                src: [
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png,webp}',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
                ]
            }
        }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
        options: {
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        },
        html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
        options: {
            assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
        },
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
        css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
    },

    // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
    imagemin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                src: '{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png}',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
            }]
        }
    },
    svgmin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
            }]
        }
    },
    htmlmin: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                removeOptionalTags: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                useShortDoctype: true
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                src: '{,*/}*.html',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            }]
        }
    },

    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
    // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
    // to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //     dist: {
    //         files: {
    //             '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //                 '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
    //                 '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //             ]
    //         }
    //     }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //     dist: {
    //         files: {
    //             '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
    //                 '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
    //             ]
    //         }
    //     }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //     dist: {}
    // },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                src: [
                    '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                    '.htaccess',
                    'images/{,*/}*.webp',
                    '{,*/}*.html',
                    'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
                    'bower_components/' + (this.includeCompass ? 'sass-' : '') + 'bootstrap/' + (this.includeCompass ? 'fonts/' : 'dist/fonts/') +'*.*'
                ]
            }]
        },
        styles: {
            expand: true,
            dot: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
            dest: '.tmp/styles/',
            src: '{,*/}*.css'
        }
    },


    // Generates a custom Modernizr build that includes only the tests you
    // reference in your app
    modernizr: {
        devFile: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
        outputFile: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
        files: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/vendor/*'
        ],
        uglify: true
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up build process
    concurrent: {
        server: [
            'compass:server',
            'copy:styles'
        ],
        test: [
            'copy:styles'
        ],
        dist: [
            'compass',
            'copy:styles',
            'imagemin',
            'svgmin'
        ]
    }
});


grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
        return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'concurrent:server',
        'autoprefixer',
        'connect:livereload',
        'watch'
    ]);
});

grunt.registerTask('server', function () {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve']);
});

grunt.registerTask('test', function(target) {
    if (target !== 'watch') {
        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'concurrent:test',
            'autoprefixer',
        ]);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
        'connect:test',
        'mocha'
    ]);
});

grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'copy:dist',
    'modernizr',
    'rev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
]);

grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
]);
};
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I came across this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20642696/how-do-i-tell-grunt-to-not-minify-or-concatenate-js-files-in-a-build-task and it works just great for me!

Answer (score 13):

I had the same desire to modify the Yeoman webapp build so that the results (javascript, css, and index.html) were not minified.  My approach was to try and modify only the Gruntfile. I wanted to avoid making any changes directly by hand to the index.html structure already provided by Yeoman.  And I wanted to avoid making any post-build manual changes to the resultant build files (too tedious).  Just wanted to build and go - no minification.

Here's what I've come up with, in case it might be helpful to others.  I narrowed this down to making two changes to the Gruntfile, as follows.

First, I modified the UseminPrepare configuration to concatenate but not uglify js files or minify css files:

In UseminPrepare, I changed this:

```
js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
css: ['cssmin']
```

To this:

```
js: ['concat'],
css: ['cssmin']
```

Second, I modified the build task series by eliminating the 'uglify' and 'htmlmin' tasks, but somewhat paradoxically you must leave the 'UseminPrepare' and 'usemin' tasks in the series.  By doing so, you leverage usemin for concatenation and copying but avoid having it minify.

Change the build task by commenting out 'uglify' and 'htmlmin' (don't forget to be sure the usemin task, now last in the series, does not end with a comma :)):

```
grunt.registerTask('build', [
 'clean:dist',
 'bowerInstall',
 'useminPrepare',
 'concurrent:dist',
 'autoprefixer',
 'concat',
 'ngmin',
 'copy:dist',
 'cdnify',
 'cssmin',
 //'uglify',
 'rev',
 'usemin'
 //'htmlmin'
]);
```

Now simply run `grunt build` and it's done.  Worked for me.

I hope that might be helpful to someone else.

Comment: +1 for direction, however for me it didn't work as described. I had to comment out also 'cssmin' in order the grunt build to work correctly

Comment: Thank you very much. Also if this suggested solution does not work for someone, he or she should try to revert the Gruntfile.js to the original and then do the steps again.

Comment: If I build as described, I see "No "cssmin" targets found.". If I remove `cssmin` as @TomasPanik suggests, I see "...views/main.html 404 (Not Found)". Not working for me.

Comment: @adamdport - you will not have to comment out cssmin from build task if you write the preparemin task like this -

    useminPrepare: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html'],
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        flow: {
          html: {
            steps: {
              js: ['concat'],
              css: ['cssmin']
            },
            post: {}
          }
        }
      }
    },

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the htmlmin task, it should stop minifying the HTML. If you want to stop minifying other things, you can remove the other *min tasks as well. All you need to remove them from is the register tasks at the bottom. However, if you don't plan on using them, it'd make sense to remove the accompanying blocks as well.

Comment: I did try that however my CSS did not compile/move to my dist folder. I'll try once more though.

Comment: If that's the case, try NOT commenting out the useminPrepare and usemin. It looks like they don't actually do the minification, but just get things ready for minification. It looks like cssmin itself doesn't move any files.

Comment: By only commenting out 'cssmin' and 'htmlmin', it all works except my css still doesn't copy to dist.

Comment: I think you'll probably need to keep in cssmin. It looks like how you have things setup, you have all of your CSS compiling to one file. To change that, you'll need to update your HTML so it uses the CSS files separately, and then add a file to your copy block to copy all of your CSS files to your dist directory. Depending how much you want the CSS to be separate, it might not be worth it.

Comment: So I'm keeping cssmin, which causes my scss to be compiled and copied to my dist folder. What do you mean by 

"To change that, you'll need to update your HTML so it uses the CSS files separately, and then add a file to your copy block to copy all of your CSS files to your dist directory"?

Answer (score 0):

If you have output style set as compressed, you have to remove that like

```
dist:
  options:
    **outputStyle: 'compressed'**
    debugInfo: false
    noLineComments: true
```

To

```
dist:
  options:
    **#outputStyle: 'compressed'** #remove it
    debugInfo: false
    noLineComments: true
```